# How to apply a conditional AND statement using Q objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
Contact(models.Model):
    personal_id = models.CharField()
    personal_id_type = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

I want to apply a `CheckConstraint` that ensures an `IntegrityError` is thrown if `personal_id` is NOT `null` AND `personal_id_type = 0`.

In pseudocode:

```
if personal_id != None and personal_id_type == 0:
    fail
```

I have tried to achieve this with the following Q objects:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
         models.CheckConstraint(check=~Q(personal_id__isnull=False) &
                                         ~Q(personal_id_type=0),
                                   name='personal_id_type_0__personal_id_isnotnull')
        ]
```

However this results in the following SQL check

```
NOT personal_id IS NOT NULL AND NOT (personal_id_type = 0 AND personal_id_type IS NOT NULL)
```

How do I amend this to be simply `NOT (personal_id_type = 0 AND personal_id_type IS NOT NULL)`?

Comment: Try removing the `~` like in the [docs][https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint]? `check=Q(personal_id__isnull=False) & Q(personal_id_type=0), name='personal_id_type_0__personal_id_isnotnull')`.. Aplogoies, I didn't see the IntegrityError

Answer (score 0):

To help those in the future, the correct approach is:

```
        models.CheckConstraint(
            check=(~Q(personal_id__isnull=False, personal_id_type=0)),
            name='personal_id_type_0__personal_id_isnotnull'
        )
```